# how to convert animation to gif unity?

Tags: export, animation, gif, animated-gif

I have made animations in Unity2d And I would like to export them as GIF files to attach to my portfolio and I cannot find a proper way to do that.
I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe the easiest option would be to record a gif directly from the screen with something like [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/)? This app allows to edit the gif later so you could remove the frames you don't want and make a perfect loop